# Invisible text even when selected (in Evince)

Tags: transparency, evince

When you process an image with an OCR tool like *tesseract*, you will get a PDF file with that image and the text invisible on top. You can't see the text, but you can select, search and copy it. When you select such text in an OCR generated PDF file it looks (in *Evince*) like this.

[image: created by tesseract]

You only see the image and the highlighting of the text. The selected text does not appear (only its highlighting). In *Evince* the highlighting for this type of text is transparent. When I try to create something like this by hand in latex, for example with the `transparent` package or `text rendering mode 3` (see code below), I get invisible text, but the highlighting appears different (in *Evince*).

[image: latex result]

When selected, the text becomes visible in the highlighting and the highlighting is not transparent as in the file generated by `tesseract`. It seems that the texts in both files are marked as different content types (or something similar), so they are highlighted differently.

### TL;DR

How can I create text like `tesseract` that is invisible, searchable, selectable and has that special highlighting (transparent, without text appearing (in *Evince*)), so you can see an image behind it even when the text is selected?

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
\fbox{Invisible 1: {\transparent{0}{invisible}}}

\fbox{Invisible 2: {\pdfliteral page{q 3 Tr}invisible\pdfliteral page{Q}}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great thanks to Nelson for his enlightening informations in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583434/226265)!

As Nelson explains, uses Evince the Poppler library to display pdf files. The
[change](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/commit/375809c897a66f42880b9ed522df3cb6bad6c305) in Poppler he mentioned, with which any selection of text in `text rendering mode 3` is displayed transparently, is included in version 20.09.0. Previously, any selection was not rendered transparently, even in files created by tesseract.

For the examples in my question I used Ubuntu 19.10 with Poppler 0.80.0 and currently I use Ubuntu 20.04 with Poppler 0.86.1. In both versions the selection in pdf files created with tesseract is displayed transparently, but not in the example from my question where I use `text rendering mode 3`.

The reason why it is already (partially) displayed correctly in older Poppler versions (on Ubuntu systems) is due to an early [patch](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/commit/?id=f0c19dafe7539f3032c71f627180dddf2bc6ac22) for Ubuntu, fixing the display of the selection for the GlyphLessFont used specifically in tesseract. This fixes the display for tesseract generated files only, while other files with `text rendering mode 3` are still displayed non-transparent.

Since Ubuntu version 20.10 the fixed Poppler version 20.09.0 is used, so that the selection of text in `text rendering mode 3` is displayed transparently in every pdf file.

---

additional information:

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306240/10252140) to a related question explains how different ocr programs store their ocr information in the pdf file.

Answer (score 3):

The `accsupp` package allows the typeset text to be different from the copy/paste text.  See **SUPPLEMENT** for alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\nosee[1]{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={\detokenize{#1}}}%
[\phantom{#1}]%
\EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
Now you see me\nosee{, now you don't}.
\end{document}
```

The PDF visual output is

[image]

If I Ctl-A, Ctl-C to copy the whole document contents and paste, the resulting text is

```
Now you see me, now you don't .
```

This latter text is searchable.  And I now allocate bracketed space equal to the text that is invisible.  If you highlight between the brackets, the text is markable, but only *in full*.  That is to say, one can either highlight the complete hidden text, or none of it.  The present approach does not allow a portion of the hidden text to be highlighted.

**SUPPLEMENT**

Here, I use `tokcycle` to process each token of the `\invisible` input stream through `\nosee` separately, thus allowing partial/continuous text highlighting.  The downside here is that the environment is intended for pure text, and any macros will only be detokenized to the cut/paste output.

This approach has the added advantage of providing line breaking.

Bracketed delimiting of the output is no longer needed...I instead output a white `\textunderscore` for each character or space encountered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accsupp,xcolor,lmodern,tokcycle}
\newcommand\nosee[1]{%
  \sbox0{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={\detokenize{#1}}}%
\makebox[\wd0]{\textcolor{white}{\textunderscore}}\allowbreak%
\EndAccSupp{}%
}
\tokcycleenvironment\invisible
{\addcytoks{\nosee{##1}}}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{\nosee{##1}}}
{\addcytoks{\nosee{ }}}
\begin{document}
Now you see me\invisible , now you don't\endinvisible.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing the copy text is interesting, but not what I'm looking for. The invisible text should be searchable **and markable**. For me this doesn't work with your approach. Maybe my question was a little bit confusing because the problem only occurs with some viewers. There seems to be a way to let the viewer know that there is another type of content so it will be marked/highlighted differently.

Comment: @Invitor It is true that I do not understand what you mean by markable, in this context.  It seems you want to be able to drag the cursor over it and acquire the text without it being visible in highlight?

Comment: @Invitor I have revised my answer...perhaps it better provides your desired behavior.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question and replaced marked by selected/highlighted.

Comment: @Invitor Thank you for the clarification.  I would note that my revised approach allows such selection **in full**.  However, as composed, one cannot perform a partial selection of the hidden text.  Is that an important feature, or is only providing full selection of the text good enough?

Comment: @Invitor I have provided a supplement to my answer, that allows partial/continuous highlighting of the invisible text, which has a more natural feel to it.

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't answer until now. I lost focus on this project (and my question). Thank you for your efforts and the really interesting things in your answer, but unfortunately it does not fix the problem with the transparent selection. Now I know that it was a bug or missing feature of my pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1):

That "transparency selection" feature was implemented in Poppler, the pdf library used by Evince and Okular. The motivation was to correctly support documents created by tesseract: see [original issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/157) and [implementation commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/commit/375809c897a66f42880b9ed522df3cb6bad6c305).

As [you can see](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/blob/poppler-21.02.0/poppler/TextOutputDev.cc#L413), a word is considered invisible when it is painted in "Text rendering mode 3", that special "no paint" mode originates from the PDF spec, as it's well explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181644).

So, it's a matter that the PDF producer software uses `Tr 3` when [inserting text](https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/pdf/text-operators) in a pdf.